# Django can't find my models in Linux but can in Windows

Tags: python, linux, django

I am somewhat still unfamiliar with Django so please excuse the possible elementary question.

am trying to deploy a Django project, but I am having some problems with it.

The project works exactly as it should on Windows, however I am getting this error on my Ubuntu VPS:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at [...]>
Traceback (most recent call last):

[...]
Stack trace from system/django files

File "/home/django/[Project Name]/apps/sale/admin.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .forms import SaleRequestFormAdmin
File "/home/django/[Project Name]/apps/sale/forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    from apps.listing.models import Listing
ImportError: No module named listing.models
```

My structure for the project is like this (with irrelevant components removed or shortened):

```
.
├── apps
│  ├── [...]
│  ├── listing
│  │  ├── admin.py
│  │  ├── api.py
│  │  ├── apps.py
│  │  ├── forms.py
│  │  ├── __init__.py
│  │  ├── migrations
│  │  │  ├── [...]
│  │  ├── models.py
│  │  ├── tests.py
│  │  └── views.py
│  ├── sale
│  │  ├── admin.py
│  │  ├── api.py
│  │  ├── apps.py
│  │  ├── forms.py
│  │  ├── __init__.py
│  │  ├── migrations
│  │  │  ├── [...]
│  │  ├── models.py
│  │  ├── tests.py
│  │  └── views.py
├── __init__.py
├── [Project Name]
│  ├── __init__.py
│  ├── settings.py
│  ├── urls.py
│  └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
```

The `apps` folder contains all of my Django apps, and is in the same folder as `manage.py` and my project folder.

You can see that there *is* a file called `models.py` in the `listing` app.

Does anyone have any idea why this does not work on Linux? I couldn't find any relevant information on Google, and I really don't know why it is failing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you added listing to your INSTALLED_APPS settings in settings.py file?

Comment: I have, as `apps.listing`.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that `apps` path is not in your `sys` path

Try adding the following in your settings.py file:

```
import os
import sys

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))
```

Let know if it helps!

Comment: Would that be in the `settings.py` file or one of the app files?

Comment: in settings file.

Comment: what is the value of PROJECT_ROOT in your case?

Comment: `/home/django/[Project Name]/[Project Folder]/settings` My settings file is in its own folder with  _\_init\_\_ set to import the correct file depending on the environment.

Comment: in that case i think you should be using BASE_DIR. sys path should have the path for your apps folder and i will work. I am personally using apps folder for my django app and I use this approach

Comment: In your /home/django/[Project Name]/apps/sale/forms.py try- from listing.models import Listing

Comment: Now it gives the error `RuntimeError: Model class listing.models.Listing doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136922/discussion-between-ajay-gupta-and-richie378).